# cutting out pennies and shillings and half-crowns and threepenny-bits

Tags: phrase-meaning

In the first chapter of Mary Poppins, Mr.Banks worked at a bank in the City.

Quote:

and while he was there he sat on a large chair in front of a large desk and made money. All day long he worked, cutting out pennies and shillings and half-crowns and threepenny-bits. And he brought them home with him in his little black bag.

Question:

What does cut out mean in the context? Was he involved in manufacturing coins? but then why he sat on a large chair in front of a large desk at work? And even if he did work as a coin manufacturer, how come he could bring some of the coins back home? Shouldn't all the coins belong to the bank?

Comment: It needs more context. It could be literal, it could be he's cutting them out of paper...

Answer (score 3):

The author is making a pun on the phrase "made money". "Made money" is an idiom in English for earning money, profiting from a business, or any other way of increasing how much money one has. However, literally the word "make" means create. As you said, a literal interpretation is that he manufactures coins. Taking some of it home with him is an extension of the humorous misinterpretation of his job. He earns a salary, but a child might misinterpret that as getting to keep some of the money he "makes".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

The book was meant for children. It was too hard to explain to them the idea behind [fractional reserve banking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional-reserve_banking), so the author made it seem like bankers earned money by literally manufacturing them at the bank where they worked, instead of how they actually do via interest rates.